# Divide multiply html tables into different pages when printing

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I have an HTML page displaying content like below:

```
<html>
    <table></table>
    <table></table>
    <table></table>
</html>
```

Now I call `window.print()`, and want each table printed onto the different pages. How can I make this?

PS: Each table may have different height

Comment: Insufficient information needs more details..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/Xugej/

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put every table in div, and set style to div like this:

`<div style="page-break-after:always;">`

This "styling" tells the browser that as soon as that div finishes everything after it should start printing on a new page. We could just as well apply the same rule to, say, all the divs on a page by adding the following to its header:

```
div {
page-break-after : always;
}
```

However, it's is more likely that you will want to apply breaks only after certain elements rather than after every paragraph. That's why it is probably better to apply the style individually or to a set of elements that you can use selectively like the DIV.

Read [this](http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/domm-4wmeu6) for more info...

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Please give Page break style to your table.

```
table{
page-break-after  : auto ;
}
```

For more info on page break please [go to link.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [page-break-after](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp) CSS property

```
<style>
    @media print
    {
        table {page-break-after:always}
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always insert a page break after each  element (when printing):

```
@media print {
    table{
          page-break-after: always;
    }
}
```

The `page-break-after` property sets whether a page break should occur AFTER a specified element.

Comment: 'page-break-after' indeed works. I tried empty div applied this style, it also works under Chrome v40. I mean add an empty div after each table

Comment: Ok. Good to know. I read this in docs and thought it was worth mentioning.