# how stop our html tables list go to next page when printing in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i create a bill receipt , upper side of bill we write some bill information's like - date, firm name , order details etc , and in second part we create a table , in which we show the list of products with quantity and rates etc.

condition-1 : when our product list be small then when we print receipt, then all is well , no blank space print in bill receipt.

condition-2 : when our product list go to longer above 12+ product.. and then we print , our printout divide in two pages , in first page only show upper part information and below that all pages show blank and our table go to next page totally .

but i want our table continue after our bill upper part completed , and table break in two parts , half in fist page and after half in next page ??i tried much but failed ??

we use this code for page print -

```
function printdiv(printpage){
var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
var footstr = "</body>";
var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = headstr+newstr+footstr;
window.print();
var xdata = <?php echo json_encode($bill_numb); ?>;
window.location = "http://localhost/itwld/index.php/account/final_bill/" + xdata;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the the no. of rows of your product details table. 
If no of rows will > 11, then break the table in multiple small table & using loop print each table. Add `page-break-after:always;` CSS property on each table also.

Comment: how we use this CSS property in table ?? please help

Comment: You can do it this way `@media print {
    table{
          page-break-after: always;
    }
}`  For more details please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050207/divide-multiply-html-tables-into-different-pages-when-printing

Comment: i tried but ..my pages goes in three pages with blank spaces .

Comment: possible to update the code, so that we can check it.